# Multiple forms of authentication for a single field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a rails project that looks to let customers authenticate their account in two separate ways. Either they can use a bar code that they have stored in the database, or they can use a phone number. I want to merge these two fields so that there will be one field that allows two sources of authentication. Here is my code for the two fields.

```
def User.authenticate(barcode)
  if user = find_by_barcode(barcode)
    user
  end
end

def User.authenticate2(phone_number)
  if user = find_by_phone_number(phone_number)
    user
  end
end
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using this one for simplicity of code:

```
def User.authenticate(barcode_or_phone_number)
  find_by_barcode(barcode_or_phone_number) || find_by_phone_number(barcode_or_phone_number)
end
```

However it might cause 2 sql to be queried. So you may consider this:

```
def User.authenticate(barcode_or_phone_number)
  where("users.barcode = ? OR users.phone_number = ?", barcode_or_phone_number, barcode_or_phone_number).first
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was the missing piece of my puzzle. I was putting the || function in my variables (barcode || phone_number)

Comment: So does my answer fix your problem?